# Reg : Exclude project option in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Q : Exclude project option in visual studio 2012?

When I am using **Exclude project** option from project for exclude particular page the particular page will be completely  left (delete) from project..I'm not possible to include the file again because there is no option showing Include project.please can I know the solution

Thanks Advance
Praveenkumar Dokula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click project -> Click Show All Files -> Right Click excluded files and include

The file are not deleted, just excluded from project

[image]

Comment: Hi Brykneval,Thanks for answer..here my problem is the file is not deleted it's remove from solution explorer..but keep into our project location.

Comment: @DokulaPraveenKumar did you try above?

Comment: ya this is correct,this way we are finding -@brykneval

Answer (score 0):

`Exclude From Project` doesn’t delete the page physically, it only removes the entry from the project (`.csproj`). `Include In Project` option is available only when an excluded page is selected. Select the project and click on `Show All Files` option in visual studio – it’ll show all files irrespective of included or excluded.